# Magento2 - Customer not Able to upload file

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I have multi-websites in Magento 2:

Url : https://www.lilysprints.co.uk/upload-an-image.html
https://nepbhprint.com/upload-an-image.html

When I try to upload an image I get this error 
Path `/var/www/vhosts/nepbhprint.com/httpdocs/var/upload/phpzIimp1` cannot be used with directory `/tmp/`

Any solution.

Comment: This sounds like a permission issue / ownership issue on that directory please see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html for magentos file system permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you Facing your issue please contact your host provider. or change your PHP version to fast CGI if using Plesk panel.